# how to check availability seats in c code linked list

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I want to show the availability of the seats in linked list, but I don't know somehow the logic in the `chekcavailability()` doesn't work.

First input is okay, the second input when I entered the same value it shows seat has been taken and return back to the particular function.

But when I enter again the different value which is available, it gives me an error.

Please help thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define A 20

struct passenger
{
char name[20];
char booking_id[20];
char passno[20];
char seatno[20];
struct passenger *next;
}*start,*curr;



void datainput(), savefile(), loadfile(), checkavailability(),   validationseat();

int main()
{
void reserve_seat(), cancel_seat(), modify_seat(), display_layout(), exit();
int choice;
start=curr=NULL;


do
{

    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n*************************************************");
    printf("\n\n********AIRLINE RESERVATION MENU*****************");
    printf("\n\n*************************************************");
    printf("\n\n\t\t* 1. Reserve seat       *");
    printf("\n\n\t\t* 2. Modify seat        *");
    printf("\n\n\t\t* 3. Cancel seat        *");
    printf("\n\n\t\t* 4. Display seat layout*");
    printf("\n\n\t\t* 5. Exit               *");
    printf("\n\n*************************************************");
    printf("\n\n\n\n\t\t Enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);fflush(stdin);
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        reserve_seat();
        break;

    case 2:
        modify_seat();
        break;

    case 3:
        cancel_seat();
        break;

    case 4:
        display_layout();
        break;
    case 5:
        {
        exit();
        break;
        }
    default:
        printf("invalid choice!!, please try again");
    }
    getch();

}while (choice != 5);

}

void datainput()
{
printf("\n\t\t enter your booking ID: ");
gets(curr->booking_id); fflush(stdin);
printf("\n\t\t enter your seat number: ");
gets(curr->seatno); fflush(stdin);
printf("\n\t\t Enter Name: ");
gets(curr->name); fflush(stdin);
printf("\n\t\t Enter Passport Number: ");
gets(curr->passno); fflush(stdin);

}

void reserve_seat()
{
curr=start;
checkavailability();
if(start==NULL)
    {
        start=curr=(struct passenger *)malloc(sizeof(struct passenger));
        datainput();
        curr->next=NULL;
        printf("\n\t data has been recorded");
        return;
    }
    while(curr->next=NULL)
        curr=curr->next;
    curr->next=(struct passenger *)malloc(sizeof(struct passenger));
    curr=curr->next;
    datainput();
    curr->next=NULL;
    printf("\n\t data has been recorded");

void checkavailability()
{
int i;
char cmp3[20];
printf("select your seat(1-20)");
gets(cmp3);fflush(stdin);
while(curr)
{
    if (strcmp(curr->seatno, cmp3)==0)
    {
        printf("Seat has been taken\n");
        checkavailability();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
printf("seat available");
return;
}
```

Comment: Take your time edit your post and then post it . ok . correct all the errors pointed by Tom . then post it

Answer (score 1):

There are many error with your code, and the worst is that he cannot compile (unless conio declare an exit function with no parameter).

First, you need to activate a decent compiler option. At least -Wall -Wextra (depend of the compiler).

In main function, this : `exit();`
The exit function need a parameter. Fix that.

```
modify_seat();
cancel_seat();
display_layout();
```

These function aren't implemented, so you shouldn't make a call to them. Fix that either.

Do not use gets ! It's dangerous and unsafe. 
Do not fflush(stdin) ! It's undefined behavior.

The "A" define is useless and not really explicite. What was it supposed to be ? "Array" ?

For your safety, try to not use global variable.
I suggest to define a structure and declare a variable in main.

In "reserve_seat" :
 while(curr->next=NULL)

you made a mistake here : it's  while(curr->next != NULL)
You assign NULL to curr->next, maybe it's the reason that why your linked list is broken.

Well, it's a dirty code for me, because it severly lack rigourous coding.
For example, check if your function call failed (like malloc).
I suggest you to rewrite the code.

Comment: sorry for  my bad behavior, actually i didnt send the full code, because its too long, i just send the specific that is matter to the problem i counter, basically i only need the logic for check the availability, thank you very much for the answer and suggestion

Comment: Yep, but for our sake, give us an MVC (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable) example, especialy because you use global variable !
Frankly, your code is like playing the russian roulette with a semi-automatic pistol.

Comment: should i ask the same question with the full code?, where should i put it by the way?

Comment: In MVC, there is M (Minimal), so no, you shouldn't put the full code.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve